# open_files_limit Centos 7 + MariaDB 10.2 - capped at 65536

Tags: mariadb, centos7

So, I have followed every step and tutorial I could find, and was able to raise the open_files_limit for MariaDB, but not to anything more than 65536.

What did I do already:

- /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service (add LimitNOFILE=infinity)
- /etc/my.cnf (open+files_limit = 1024000 to both [mysqld] as [mysqld_safe]
- /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limits.conf (add [Service] LimitNOFILE=infinity)
- /etc/sysctl.conf (tried fs.file-max=100000)
- /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limit_nofile.conf and etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limit_nofile.conf LimitNOFILE=infinity)

after each step of course:

- systemctl daemon-reload
- systemctl restart mysql
- systemctl stop mariadb
- systemctl start mariadb

even rebooted multiple times

So, perhaps 65536 is enough, but I normally use a higher value without issues. To prevent further issues, I want it raised. Who can chime in and help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have learned the lesson; move on.

65K files is an "unreasonably" high limit.  Several thousand is almost always sufficient.  1,024,000 is ludicrous; the OS will probably croak.

MySQL/MariaDB needs a "few" files for each table in use.  But MySQL is happy to "cache" the open files, and does not have to have room for all of them.  Even so, 65K is enough for more than 10K tables -- which is also unreasonably high.

Comment: alright. It is just that I want to be in control. My machine, my control. 'you shall listen to me'. Now it has it's own mind and I'm curious where the setting is, but will have to let it go. Thanks!

Comment: Here are some more "hard" limits that you won't be able to get past:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits .  If you find any bugs in that list, I would be happy to know and fix.  (Since `ulimit` seems to be an OS limit, I have not included it.)